# Moment.js add 7 days to current date in ISO format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have the date, which comes from server in the ISO format: 2019-02-28.
How can I add 7 days to it, using Moment.js?

The result should be 2019-03-04.

Comment: What have you tried, and what is the problem with it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've tried this:

startdate = "20.03.2014";
var new_date = moment(startdate, "DD-MM-YYYY").add(7, 'days');

alert(new_date);

But the date is not in ISO format

Comment: What do you mean *"the date is not in ISO format"*? In your question you say that it *is*. Does it work if your `startdate` actually matches the format you tell `moment` it's in? You're currently trying to parse `DD.MM.YYYY` as `DD-MM-YYYY`, which cannot be expected to succeed, and neither is the ISO format you claim your server provides.

Comment: "20.03.2014" is not an ISO 8601 format and is inconsistent with the parse format you're passing to moment.js of "DD-MM-YYYY".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this solution and let me know if it works.

```
moment('2019-02-28').add(7,'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If your date is actually in ISO 8601 format, you don't need to specify the format - https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/